# Protected Header JWS

Tags: json, encryption, jwt, jose

I'm trying to understand [this blog post about JOSE](https://ordina-jworks.github.io/security/2016/03/12/Digitally-signing-your-JSON-documents.html). In the part about JWS, it says the following:

> Including the public key in the protected header would not only give
>   the server the ability the validate the signature, we will also be
>   sure that it is the correct one since the protected header is
>   integrity protected!

This is what the example object looks like:

```
{
    "payload": "eyAKICAgICAgICAiZnJvbSI6ewogICAgICAgICAgICAibmFtZSI6ICJUaW0gWXNld3luIiwKICAgICAgICAgICAgImFjY291bnQiOiAiQ2hlY2tpbmcgYWNjb3VudCIKICAgICAgICB9LAogICAgICAgICJ0byI6ewogICAgICAgICAgICAibmFtZSI6ICJUaW0gWXNld3luIiwKICAgICAgICAgICAgImFjY291bnQiOiAiU2F2aW5ncyBhY2NvdW50IgogICAgICAgIH0sCiAgICAgICAgImFtb3VudCI6IDI1MAogICAgICAgICJjdXJyZW5jeSI6ICJFVVIiCiAgICB9",
    "protected": "eyAKICAgICAgICAiYWxnIjogIlJTMjU2IgogICAgfQ==",
    "header": {
        "signature": "DtEhU3ljbEg8L38VWAfUAqOyKAM6-Xx-F4GawxaepmXFCgfTjDxw5djxLa8ISlSApmWQxfKTUJqPP3-Kg6NU01Q"
    }
}
```

The protected header is the `base64url` encoding of:

```
{ 
    "alg": "ES256"
}
```

The only reference I can find to putting a public key in there is the use of the key id field `kid` like so:

```
{"alg":"RSA1_5","kid":"2011-04-29"}
```

Is this what the post is referring to? Or is it referring to something else (like putting the entire public key into the protected header as:

```
{"alg":"RSA1_5","key":"somepublickeyhere"}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are on the right path. What the article is probably referring to is the `"jwk"` header parameter defined in [RFC-7515](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7515#section-4.1.3) as follows:

> The "jwk" (JSON Web Key) Header Parameter is the public key that
> corresponds to the key used to digitally sign the JWS.  This key is
> represented as a JSON Web Key.

JSON Web Key (JWK) is another part of JOSE defined in [RFC-7517](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7517). It defines how to represent cryptographic keys in JSON format so they can be transmitted e.g. in a JWS header. An RSA key in JWK format might look something like this:

```
{
  "kty":"RSA",
  "n": "0vx7 (...) DKgw",
  "e":"AQAB",
  "alg":"RS256",
  "kid":"2011-04-29"
}
```

And a (protected) JWS header carrying a key, as described in the article, therefore might look like this:

```
{
  "alg": "RS256",
  "jwk": {
    "kty":"RSA",
    "n": "0vx7 (...) DKgw",
    "e":"AQAB",
    "alg":"RS256",
    "kid":"2011-04-29"
  }
}
```